# New relic showing Transaction as views.function_name for pyhton services while I want to show API endpoint

Tags: django, transactions, newrelic

I am checking transaction data for one of my APIs on Django and getting new relic Transactions as a.views:function1_name and a.views.function2_name, while I want to show API endpoints in transactions. How can I do this?